# I keep getting incorrect output for my second largest number program (C Program)

Tags: c

I'm having trouble getting the correct output in my program for finding the second largest number out of three numbers. (I know it's really basic, but I've just begun learning C, so any help and tips would be appreciated!) In my program, I get the max and the min of the three numbers (no problem there) but I keep getting the answer 204 for the second largest number. (which is wrong!) Here's my code, sorry if there's any awful mistakes, like I said, I'm new to this! Thank you so much! :)

```
//include the libraries

#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>

//include the main function

int main()
{

    //declare the variables
    long a,b,c,min,max,secmax;

    //read the variables
    printf("a=");scanf("%ld",&a);
    printf("b=");scanf("%ld",&b);
    printf("c=");scanf("%ld",&c);

    // Find the min of the 3 numbers.
    if( b>a && c>a)
    {
        min=a;
    }
    else
    {
        min==b || min==c;
    }

    if( a>b && c>b )
    {
        min=b;
    }
    else
    {
        min==a || min==c;
    }

    if( a>c && b>c)
    {
        min=c;
    }
    else
    {
        min==a || min==b;
    }

    // Find the max of the 3 numbers.

    if( b>a && b>c)
    {
        max=b;
    }
    else
    {
        max==a || max==c;
    }

    if( a>b && a>c )
    {
        max=a;
    }
    else
    {
        max==b || max==c;
    }

    if( c>a && c>a)
    {
        max=c;
    }
    else
    {
        max==a || max==b;
    }

    //Find the second largest number
    if(a!=max && a!=min)
    {
       a=secmax;
    }
    else
    {
        b==secmax || c==secmax;
    }

    if(b!=max && b!=min)
    {
       b=secmax;
    }
    else
    {
        a==secmax || c==secmax;
    }

    if(c!=max && c!=min)
    {
       c=secmax;
    }
    else
    {
        b==secmax || a==secmax;
    }

    //print the output
    printf("\nThe maximum is %d\n",max);
    printf("\nThe second largest number is %d\n",secmax); 
    printf("\nThe minimum is %d\n",min);

getch();

return 1;
}
```

Comment: What inputs are you giving it?  Also, these blocks of code: `else
    {
        min==b || min==c;
    }` make no sense to me.

Comment: I input a=3, b=5 and c=8. Ok, should I take them out entirely? :)

Comment: And based on `a=3`, `b=5`, `c=8`, it tells you that `204` is the second largest number...?

Comment: yes, it's so confusing!

Comment: What are these `else { min==b || min==c; }` supposed to be doing exactly...?  Also, there's a typo here: `if( c>a && c>a)
    {
        max=c;
    }`

Comment: This bit of code:
    `if( b>a && c>a)
    {
        min=a;
    }
    else
    {
        min==b || min==c;
    }`

Doesn't make sense programmatically. Semantically I understand what you are trying to do: If a  is not the smallest than the smallest is either b or c. But you don't have to specify this in terms of code. The lines:
    `else
    {
        min==b || min==c;
    }`

Literally do nothing. This applies to every other if-else statement you have.

Comment: This is so beautiful.

Comment: You don't initialize max and min before you use it in the odd-looking lines such as `min==b || min==c;`. It would probably be easier to write: `min = a; if (b < min) min = b; if (c < min) min = c;` and now `min` is fixed.  Then you can do `max = a; if (b > max) max = b; if (c > max) max = c;` and now `max` is fixed.  And then you can do `mid = a; if (b != min && b != max) mid = b; if (c != min && c != max) mid = c;`  to determine the middle (second largest, second smallest) value.  If the values are distinct, you're home and dry; if not, you've got some definitional work to do...

Comment: why not use some sort algorithm (bubble, quicksort) and print the result?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Should post that as the answer and let questioner accept it.

Comment: @ensc op seems to be very new at programming. The idea of sorting is probably beyond their scope of understanding right now. Although practically speaking I would just pop them in an array and call some sorting algorithm on it.

Comment: Jonathan, I just tried that and it worked. :) Thank you so much for your help, I also realise my mistake not initialising the variables! Sorry for the silly lines, beginner mistake! also, @ensc not quite at that level yet, but hopefully I will be someday! thank you all so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment works this way:

```
...
secmax = a;
...
```

This line of code assigns `a` to `secmax`. If `secmax` didn't contain anything (contained "garbage" in programmer jargon), after executing this line it will be equal to `a`. This is what you want.

---

```
a = secmax;
```

This line of code is no good - it does the opposite of what you want. It's probably a typo.

---

There are other problems with your code, but this one seems the most important to fix; there is a chance your code will work after fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Find the min of the 3 numbers.
if (b>a && c>a)  
{  
  min = a;  
}  
else if(a>b && c>b)  
{  
  min = b;  
}  
else  
{  
  min = c;  
}
```

This will properly set the min. You can use similar logic/control flow to set max, and based on the min/max, figure out the middle value.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is to get rid of all the **else** checks you currently have. They are just evaluating bool results and doing nothing with them.

Second, when you are finding the **second largest number** you are assigning secmax into a, b &c but in actuality it should be like this:

```
if(a!=max && a!=min)
{
   secmax = a;
}

if(b!=max && b!=min)
{
   secmax = b;
}

if(c!=max && c!=min)
{
   secmax = c;
}
```